# 2013 to 2016 Migration Errors

Tags: 2013, 2016, migration

Before the command `Mount-SPContentDatabase`, there were no errors `Test-SPContentDatabase`, I checked for
These errors appeared after the command `Mount-SPContentDatabase -name WSS_Content –WebApplication http://sp`

1:

> MissingWebPart,"True","False","WebPart class
>   [6a1f4b36-329d-317b-802a-96130a9ae5e7] (class
>   [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.BusinessDataFilterWebPart]
>   from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1]
>   times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the
>   current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this
>   web part.","One or more web parts are referenced in the database
>   [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please
>   install any feature or solution which contains these web parts.",

2:

> MissingWebPart,"True","False","WebPart class
>   [69a2a58c-9b8d-d5c5-a7f6-a0feeeaf3867] (class
>   [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SpListFilterWebPart] from
>   assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [10]
>   times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the
>   current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this
>   web part.","One or more web parts are referenced in the database
>   [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please
>   install any feature or solution which contains these web parts.",

All solutions is installed PowerShell:

```
Install-SPSolution -Identity "solution.wsp" -GACDeployment -force -CompatibilityLevel All
```

Comment: Is this occurring on all the pages? 
Are you able to access site settings page (/_layouts/settings.aspx)? 
Is this web.config customized?
Do you get the same error if you create a default SP2016 web application without any customizations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you migrate the sites on Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 to SharePoint Server 2016, the following web part controls no longer work on the migrated sites:

- SpListFilterWebPart
- ExcelWebRenderer
- ReportViewerWebpart

[Web part controls don't work after sites are migrated to SharePoint 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4013911/some-web-parts-do-not-work-after-the-sites-is-migrated-to-sharepoint)

My solution: I find my Web Part in DataBase and re-created FilterWebPart on Page:

```
SELECT * from AllDocs inner join AllWebParts on AllDocs.Id = AllWebParts.tp_PageUrlID where AllWebParts.tp_WebPartTypeID = '69a2a58c-9b8d-d5c5-a7f6-a0feeeaf3867'
```

or add row in web.config:

```
<SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" TypeName="SpListFilterWebPart" Safe="True" />
<SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" TypeName="BusinessDataFilterWebPart" Safe="True" />
```